# android -parse not receives on the phone

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm using parse for sending notifications .I wrote this code and it works find on emulator but I get the notifications on phones . this is the manifest:

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="mypackagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="mypackagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

<application
        android:name="mypackagename.ParseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!-- IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications" to match your app's package name. -->
                <category android:name="mypackagename.MessageAll" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="mypackagename.MessageAll"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="mypackagename.MessageAll" />
                <action android:name="MessageAll" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

for mypackagename I use my package name .

in the parseApplication :

```
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.PushService;

public class ParseApplication extends android.app.Application {

  public ParseApplication() {
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Parse.initialize(this, "9OaXWT76IDHlZiwQVaGwECw7LISflGmLmDJf0VTa", "0JcMfXSQPn2oJpH6x8qR2gJhG41U17nVOXOWmIIK");
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, FistActiivty.class);
  }
}
```

I've changed these two values with new codes from parse keys .

when I debug it on the phone ,I get this message:

> com parse PushService: Tried to use push, but this app is not configured for push due to: Push is not configured for this app because the app manifest is missing required declarations. Please add the following declarations to your app manifest to support either GCM or PPNS for push (or both). To enable GCM support, please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:

what is wrong ? I don't get it .

Comment: I think you can find this solution here. https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/165